# Is it possible to create multiple instances from a class that use Intent-filters and broadcasts?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to scale a solution that used to connect to a single BLE device. I am doing so by creating multiple instances of 2 classes that use broadcasting heavily to couple their execution sequence.

I have 3 classes named `Device`, `Sequence`, and `Bluetooth`.

`Sequence` and `Bluetooth` are the ones using broadcasts & filter-intents. For each BLE device, 3 new instances will be created from `Device`, `Sequence`, and `Bluetooth`.

I am seeing weird behavior in the `Sequence` and `Bluetooth` so I wanted to confirm if I need to use a unique intent filter for each created instance from `Sequence` and `Bluetooth`?

And is it possible to change intent-filters dynamically when constructing the class?

I truly appreciate any help

```
public class Bluetooth {
   private final static String TAG = BluetoothBle.class.getSimpleName();
   private Context mContext;// I am using the Applicationcontext
   private Boolean mDisconnectScheduledFlag = false;//in case we issue disconnect while timer is working

   //Run send data in thread
   private HandlerThread mHandlerThread;
   private Handler mHandler;
   private  int mIntervalBetweenTwoPackag =100;
   private Boolean mDisconnectedFlag = false;

   private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
   private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
   private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
   private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
   private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;

   private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
   private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
   private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

//Intent Filters - Do i need to change . create them dynamically for every created instance of the class
   private static final  String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
           "com.hworld.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
   private static final  String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
           "com.world.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
   private static final  String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
           "com.world.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
   private static final  String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
           "com.world.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
   private static final  String EXTRA_DATA =
           "com.world.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";
   private static final  String CLASS_CONSTRUCTED =
           "com.world.bluetooth.le.CLASS_CONSTRUCTED";

   LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager;

   private int ble_status = FREE;
   private int packet_counter = 0;
   private int send_data_pointer = 0;
   private byte[] send_data = null;
   private boolean first_packet = false;
   private boolean final_packet = false;
   private boolean packet_send = false;
   private Timer mTimer;
   private int time_out_counter = 0;
   private int TIMER_INTERVAL = 100;
   private int TIME_OUT_LIMIT = 100;
   private ArrayList<byte[]> data_queue = new ArrayList<>();
   boolean sendingStoredData = false;

   // Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
   // connection change and services discovered.
   private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
       @Override
       public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
           String intentAction;
           if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
               Log.d(TAG, "CONNECTED");
               intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
               mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
               broadcastUpdate(intentAction);

               // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
               Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start com.wakeup.bluetoothtest.service discovery:" +
                       mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

               int obj_id = System.identityHashCode(mGattCallback);
               Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange mGattCallback_obj_id:" + obj_id +" - A:"+ mBluetoothDeviceAddress);

               mDisconnectedFlag = false;

           } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
               Log.d(TAG, "DISCONNECTED");
               intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
               mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
               broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
               /*App.mConnected = false;
               close(true);*/
               mDisconnectedFlag = true;
           }
       } //End of function onConnectionStateChange
      
   private SendDataToBleReceiver sendDataToBleReceiver;

   private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
       final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
       mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
   }

 public BluetoothBle(Context context, String extraFilter){
   if (mContext == null && context != null)
       mContext = context;

/*    //Add unique number to filter
   if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(extraFilter)){
       ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
               "com.world.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED." + extraFilter;
       ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
               "com.world.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED." + extraFilter;
       ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
               "com.world.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
       ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
               "com.world.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
       EXTRA_DATA =
               "com.world.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";
       CLASS_CONSTRUCTED =
               "com.world.bluetooth.le.CLASS_CONSTRUCTED";
   }*/

   localBroadcastManager= LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);

   sendDataToBleReceiver = new SendDataToBleReceiver();
   IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
   intentFilter.addAction(BleConstans.ACTION_SEND_DATA_TO_BLE);
  
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
.registerReceiver(sendDataToBleReceiver, intentFilter);
   broadcastUpdate(CLASS_CONSTRUCTED);
 }
}
```

I run my operation sequence inside the class below:

```
public class BandT1sSequence  implements UiThreadCallback {
    private final static String TAG = BandT1sSequence.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final  String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
            "com.world.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
    private static final  String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
            "com.world.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
    private static final  String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
            "com.world.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
    private static final  String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
            "com.world.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
    private static final  String EXTRA_DATA =
            "com.world.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";
    private static final  String CLASS_CONSTRUCTED =
            "com.world.bluetooth.le.CLASS_CONSTRUCTED";

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String mExtraFilter;

    private Boolean closeCompletedFlag = false;
    private Boolean clearQueuesFlag = false;

    /Constructor
    public  BandT1sSequence(Context context){
        if (context!=null && mContext ==null)
            mContext = context;

        Log.d(TAG, "BandT1sSequence constructor");
        //AE - Malaysia
        mCommandManager = CommandManager.getInstance(mContext);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        intThread();

        mExtraFilter = Integer.toString(System.identityHashCode(mHandlerThread));

        //System.identityHashCode(mBluetoothLeClass)
        //Create bluetooth class
        mBluetoothLeClass = new BluetoothBle(context,mExtraFilter);

        //confirm the object identity
        dataHelper = DataHelper.getsInstance(context);
      
        //Register broadcast receivers
        if (mBluetoothLeClass != null)
            mContext.registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
    }

    private IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
        intentFilter.addAction(CLASS_CONSTRUCTED);
        return intentFilter;
    }

    public void connectToDevice (){
        if (mBluetoothLeClassConstructed &&  mBluetoothLeClass!=null && bandConnectionFlag==false ) {
            mDeviceConnectedFlag= mBluetoothLeClass.connect(mDeviceAddress);

            int obj_id = System.identityHashCode(mBluetoothLeClass);
            Log.d(TAG, "BandT1sSequence connect to device mBluetoothLeClass_obj_id:" + obj_id +" - "+ getBandDetails());

            //device1ConnectionStarted=true;
        }else
            Log.d(TAG, "connectToDevice: can't connect " + mBluetoothLeClassConstructed);
    }

 private BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            bluetoothIntentAction = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(bluetoothIntentAction)) {
                if (!mSequence.settingModeFlag){
                    sendRunnableToHandlerThread(syncRunnable);
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange: threads count " + java.lang.Thread.activeCount() +" - current thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED");
            } else if (ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(bluetoothIntentAction)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED B: " + mDeviceName +"-"+mDeviceAddress );
                
                mBluetoothLeClass.close();
                bandConnectionFlag = false;
            } else if (ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(bluetoothIntentAction)) {
              
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Broadcast Receiver is costly & heavy resource. I would suggest to make that class singleton so that you don't end up creating multiple objects of class that contains broadcast receiver which can lead to concerns on memory usages.

Comment: @JeelVankhede But how to synchronize between the 2 classes , through call backs ?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways like Rx observables, LiveData or Callback interfaces etc..